# Getting stopevent from ProblemSteps Recorder using command line

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm looking to integrate the [Problem Steps recorder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-use-Problem-Steps-Recorder) available in Windows 7+ into my c# application to allow users to record bugs in my software. The [command line](http://ctrlf5.net/?p=176) arguments allow a `/stopevent` to be specified. How does this work? How can I hook this into my .NET app?